# How to draw image in x-direction?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I have one issue that i want to animate graphs. For that i have transparent static images for the each graph it is horizontal graph means left to right graph.

Now i do not want to expand this images like first we kept the width=0 and with animation we can increase the width to the images original width, i do not want this.

I want that the image see like the graph is drawing for example Cardiograph. I have static image of Cardiograph and want to show that it is animating.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your image over say a white background. The whole graph image. Crate another completely white view and overlay that over the graph image. Then you can animate the top image so the left side slowly moves to the right - so x increases as width decreases.

EDIT: For example, if you have three views, and you want to animate something over all three, you can use something like the code below, which slowly shows a solid color overlay over each view, then apparently slides out of view to the left (like a curtain):

```
UIView *coverView1 = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ {0,0}, graph1View.frame.size}];
coverView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
coverView1.alpha = 0;
[graphView1 addSubview:coverView1];

UIView *coverView2 = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ {0,0}, graph2View.frame.size}];
coverView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
coverView2.alpha = 0;
[graphView2 addSubview:coverView2];

UIView *coverView3 = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ {0,0}, graph3View.frame.size}];
coverView3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
coverView3.alpha = 0;
[graphView3 addSubview:coverView3];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
{
  coverView1.alpha = 1;
  coverView2.alpha = 1;
  coverView3.alpha = 1;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
  {
    CGRect frame;
    frame = coverView1.frame, frame.size.width = 0, coverView1.frame = frame;
    frame = coverView2.frame, frame.size.width = 0, coverView2.frame = frame;
    frame = coverView3.frame, frame.size.width = 0, coverView3.frame = frame;
  }
  completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {
    [coverView1 removeFromSuperview];
    [coverView2 removeFromSuperview];
    [coverView3 removeFromSuperview];
   } ];
} ];
```

This code typed in here so may have small typos etc.

Comment: i have already tried this but what happen one graph is done well in this condition. But i have three graphs in the same screen so what happen for the first graph it looks good but when i draw the second graph the the first one will hide untill the second graph draw completes, right? so is there any other way like context drawing like that.

Comment: You would use one animation block, and you can do the same or different animations in all the graphs in your view. You can use logic to decide to animate one and show the other two, animate all of them etc. If its all in one block it will be very smooth and look very nice.

Comment: Do you have any sample for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your image as circular buffer. In other words, you just move you anchor x coordinate.

Comment: if i move the x- coordinate then image position also moves.